# Performing Vlookup on duplicate values

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

First of all I know how to perform VLookup for unique values.

Now I have a set of data with me where in the 'Table Array' I have a lot of duplicate values which needs to be associated with a single 'Look UP value'

For example.
[image: Lookup value]

[image: Table Array]

As you can see in the table array there are duplicate values.

I am not sure how to use the Vlook Up here.

Comment: do you need to count these?

Comment: @DougCoats   No.. I want to do a simple Vlook up kind of thing where i want the lookup value to be associated with the table array and return data from column A.

Comment: So, if you lookup `ACB002`, you want a formula that will return `CKDMST`, then the next cell (assuming you drag the formula) will be `ACDMST`?  Or the other way around?

Comment: @BruceWayne EXactly !!

Comment: Check out [this page](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/42382-extracting-data-vlookup-how-handle-duplicates.html) for some idea, does anything there work? Or [this one](http://forum.chandoo.org/threads/how-to-use-vlookup-when-there-are-duplicate-values-in-the-list.15825/).  What have you tried so far? [Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=vlookup%20with%20duplicate%20values) has a bunch of results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [excel vlookup with multiple results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754605/excel-vlookup-with-multiple-results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an array, if the data was in the above format and your lookup was James in B2, you could say in F2

Use

```
=INDEX($B$2:$C$22,SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$22=$B$2,ROW($B$2:$B$22)-1),1),2)
=INDEX($B$2:$C$22,SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$22=$B$2,ROW($B$2:$B$22)-1),2),2)
=INDEX($B$2:$C$22,SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$22=$B$2,ROW($B$2:$B$22)-1),3),2)
```

I haven't tested just yet, I will do so in a moment, however dragging down will essentially increase the count in ROWS, so will increase the selection from the SMALL function

Answer (score 0):

Say we have data like:

[image]

and we want to *VLOOKUP()* all the *Michael* data  values.  In **A2** enter:

```
=IF(B2="Michael",1+MAX($A$1:A1),"")
```

and copy down.  Then in another cell enter:

```
=IF(ROWS($1:1)>MAX(A:A),"",VLOOKUP(ROWS($1:1),$A$2:$C$22,3))
```

and copy down:

[image]

As you see, column **A** allows us to do an easy lookup on simple, sequential, integers.