# Excel subset column to an array using formula

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, match

I need to get the Account Numbers into an array which is indicated as 1 on the column select. Results expected is - {FD_002_17,FD_004_17}. I am planning to use this in a Name Range.
[Table of interest to subset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBTxY.jpg)

I tried using

```
=INDEX(B2:B6,MATCH(1,A2:A6),1)
```

But this fails as `Match` does not return an array.

Answer (score 1):

Using the post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6755513/4050510) in the SO question that Hugs referred to i came up with the following formula for your need.

Its a array formula that you enter into your first cell, and then fill it downwards using the little handle in the corner of the selected cell.

`=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$6;SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$6=1;ROW($B$2:$B$6)-MIN(ROW($B$2:$B$6))+1;"");ROW(A1)));"")`

[image]

Comment: Ah! I see this is not a solution after all, since it wont return the answer *as an array*. Sorry. I'll leave it around since it might provide inspiration to someone.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes it is not returning an array.  I want to use this as a dynamic array for a drop down. Appreciate if you could help me with this. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this. You can assign the named range to a formula such as :

`=INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B, N(IF({1}, MODE.MULT(IF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$6=1, ROW(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$6)*{1,1})))))`

Then you can reference your Named Range like: `=INDEX(MyNamedRange, 2)`

**EDIT:**

You can either set a hidden sheet to have a filtered list of the values in a range of cells, or else use VBA:

**VBA:**

Put this in the worksheet codemodule of the relevant work sheet:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

  Dim ARange As Range, BRange As Range
  Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long, strCount As Long
  lastRow = Me.Range("A" & Me.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  Set ARange = Me.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
  Set BRange = Me.Range("B1:B" & lastRow)

  Dim stringArr() As String
  For i = 1 To lastRow
        If ARange.Cells(i, 1).Value = 1 Then
              ReDim Preserve stringArr(0 To strCount)
              stringArr(strCount) = BRange.Cells(i, 1).Value
              strCount = strCount + 1
        End If
  Next i

  Dim str As String
  str = Join(stringArr, ",")

  Dim dv As Validation
  Set dv = Me.Range("DVCell").Validation
  If Not dv Is Nothing Then
        dv.Modify _
              Type:=xlValidateList, _
              AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
              Operator:=xlBetween, _
              Formula1:=str
  Else
        dv.Add _
              Type:=xlValidateList, _
              AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
              Operator:=xlBetween, _
              Formula1:=str

  End If
 End Sub
```

To use formulas and a hidden sheet, use the techniques to fill a range of cells, and then assign that dynamic range to the data validation....

Comment: Thanks for your response. Stil the problem remains as this formula returns only one value not the array with two values as for the example.

Comment: I guarantee that this formula DOES return an array. That's specifically what  it does. If you use a named range as you said, and call Index on the named range you can get any entry. IF you are trying to enter this in cells directly, you must use Ctrl-Shift-Enter. I am not sure what you're doing. If you show what you're doing, we can see the problem.

Comment: Hi @MacroMarc Yes, you are correct. I am trying to use `MyNamedRange` as a dynamic list into a dropdown but it does not return any value. Can you please help me with that? Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately data validation lists can only take a range of cells or a comma separated list(typed in the Data Validation dialogue box). They don't work well with arrays which result from a formula construction such as mine. You can use formulas to set a range of cells, but in your situation, you are trying to filter a range into an array. It won't work. See my edited answer

Comment: Thanks @MacroMarc this explains why i was failing with different approaches tried to assign an array to dropdown in exccel.

Comment: Shana, to expand on the formula only method, if you use either my formula (or the other posters), and write out the values to a range of cells in a hidden worksheet. You can then apply a Named Range to that range of cells, and then use that named Range for the data validation. If you start the values from A2 in the Hidden Sheet, then you would have a named range pointing like: `='Hidden Sheet'!$A$2:INDEX('Hidden Sheet'!$A:$A, MIN(IF('Hidden Sheet'!$A:$A="", ROW('Hidden Sheet'!$A:$A)))-1)`. That would give the named range to be used in the DV list.