# excel concate third column based on first two columns

Tags: excel, concatenation, vba

[sample Data [image: sample Data]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAjz2.png)

[Result data[image: Result data]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHeLD.png)

Basically Location+IP is the primary key. Based on primary key i want concatenate the third column user separated by commas.
I am new to excel please help.

Comment: i think you are wanting to concatenate as a comma separated string all matches in users column for a lookup based on unique combinations of location + ip columns. You might consider using helper columns and a pre-defined named range with the possible unique keys. See answer by Chris0 here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754605/excel-vlookup-with-multiple-results   There are other examples on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. sort location,IP using custom sort option.

   2. =IF(CONCATENATE(A2,B2)<>CONCATENATE(A1,B1),C2,D1 & "," &C2).
   3. Use another condition to create blank in unwanted rows - =IF(CONCATENATE(A2,B2)<>CONCATENATE(A3,B3),CONCATENATE(D2,"",),"")
   4. Apply filter and remove blank columns
   5. copy paste and delete unwanted columns
      [image: step1 - custom sort]
      [image: step2 - formula 1]
      [image: step3- result after apply formula]
      [image: step 4 - formula 4]
      [image: step5 - result after apply formula 2]
      [image: step6-Apply filter - deselect blank]
      [image: step7-Copy paste and delete unwanted columns]

Comment: Image not appearing . I don't know why ?

Answer (score 0):

Select all data and insert a pivot table to summarize the data.

Insert Pivot table

[image]

Summarize your data
[image]

Comment: Could you pls explain in detail ?